# In OCaml, what is the canonical way of matching against multiple arguments of a function?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

You could pattern-match against multiple arguments of a function by creating a tuple and then destructuring it in a match expression:

```
let f x y =
  match x, y with
  | pattern1 -> expr1
  | ...
```

Alternatively, if you don't need a curried function, you could do this by making `f` take a tuple as the only argument:

```
let f (x, y) = function
  | pattern1 -> expr1
  | ...
```

The advantage of the latter method is that you don't have to write the arguments twice every time you define a function.  But functions that take a tuple seems to be not as popular than curried ones.

So which of the two is deemed canonical, or preferred, in the OCaml community?

EDIT: Just as pad pointed out below, I mean `let f = function blah blah` in the second code snippet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A tuple is not just a syntactic construct, it represents a real data structure. This means that `fun (x,y)` is (very slightly) less efficient than `f x y` in the case were `x` and `y` aren't already tupled, because a tuple has to be allocated. If this isn't clear, the rough equivalent in Java would be

```
void foo(X x, Y y) { ... }
void bar(Tuple<X,Y> t) { ... }

/* client code */
X x = new X();
Y y = new Y();

foo(x, y);  // Just uses x and y directly
bar(new Tuple<X,Y>(x, y)); // Has to "new" a Tuple
```

For this reason, it's generally preferable to avoid using tuples as function arguments unless you have a good reason to do so.

P.S. A similar consideration applies to datatype declarations, where the following are subtly different:

```
type 'a foo = Foo of 'a * 'a;
type 'a bar = Bar of ('a * 'a);
```

`Foo` is a datatype constructor that takes two arguments. `Bar` is a constructor that takes one argument (a tuple).

Answer (score 18):

This solution is canonical:

```
let f x y =
  match x, y with
  | pattern1 -> expr1
  | ...
```

The compiler optimizes this special case and does not actually allocate a block for the tuple `(x, y)`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, `f = function...` is a shortcut of `f (x, y) = match (x, y) with...` so:

```
let f = function 
  | pattern1_of_x_y -> expr1
  | ...
```

is the same as:

```
let f (x, y) =
  match x, y with
  | pattern1 -> expr1
  | ...
```

(Notice that there is a mistake in your second formulation; those two versions are not compatible).

As you pointed out, one cannot avoid using `match ... with...` in a curried function. Personally, I prefer the curried form of a function since it is more flexible, especially with partial application. Moreover, pattern matching is not only applied in function arguments; they are used essentially everywhere in OCaml, which makes `match ... with...` construct even more important.

Whenever you spot the usage pattern as above, try to replace `match ... with...` with `function`. It is just a matter of style, so there is nothing more prefered here.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical way is a curried function and to `match` on the tuple, i.e. your first snippet.

This is the way the standard library is written (look at the standard library sources, for example many functions in `list.ml`).

This is also the way that the implementation is optimized for, especially the native code compiler. If you create a tuple or other block and destroy it immediately without passing it to functions that expect a block, the native code compiler often spots that and avoids allocating a block altogether. Even if you end up allocating a block, it's more efficient to make the duration of the block as short as possible, to increases the chances that the block remains in the minor heap and in the processor cache.